# CSS flex: odd behavior

Tags: css, flexbox

Please consider the following example:

https://jsfiddle.net/mr4fapx7/1/

```
<div class="z">
  <div class="z1">1</div>
  <div class="z1">2</div>
  <div class="z1">3</div>
</div>

.z {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  /* flex-direction: column; */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 1000px;
  background: #900;
}
.z1 {
  min-width: 51%;
  background: #0f0;
}
```

I can't understand this behavior of flex... why does `z1` els aren't aligned one after another as if you apply `flex-direction: column` to it? What is the logic behind it and is there a good way of making it "automatically" switch as if it where `flex-direction: column` as in this example?

UPDATE:
seems like I didn't explain myself correctly. Please try the above example with uncommented `flex-direction` property and see the desired behavior

Comment: Flex is to be applied to parent only and by default the flex direction is for row. if you need column then you have to specify that.

Comment: @Manjuboyz can you elaborate your answer please? As I understand it, if the flex parent has flex-wrap set and children has more than 51% of width, they should behave as if it were flex-direction column

Comment: when you say `51%` it should refer to some parent `width` isn't it, the reason it was not working as you say because you didn't specify the width value for the parent, Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because the flex parent has a height of 1000px, the space between the elements is equally distributed.

If you want the items to come one item after another, you have to set `align-content : start` to your flex parent and you should be good.

I am assuming that you set the min-width to 51% just to test things out and not something else.

Here's updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/81nrf6ug/

Comment: OMFG... dude! You rock! :D
I never used this before... never! Can't believe this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: the 51% is for testing, of course. the whole example is for testing :)

Comment: Glad it helped! :)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried with a lower min-width value or removing the min-width property. The min width is 51% and if you want all the three columns in same row, the total would be 153% and total width should not be more than 100%.

Comment: Apparently there has been misunderstanding, please read the updated post

Comment: OK. I suppose `align-content: start` has solved your issue as mentioned above.